# Thread Sleep in Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm doing some revision on an old app that is written in classic ASP/VbScript.

It has a feature to send out an e-mail to the members of the application, but because the member list is quite large, the server rejects new e-mails after the first hundred or so are sent.

I've written some code to make it send out e-mails in burst of 20, but this still doesn't work. I think that perhaps making it sleep for a second between burst might work properly.

However, I can't seem to find a Thread.Sleep type method in VbScript.

Is there one?

Comment: You *KNOW* that the server is rejecting the emails because they are coming at it too fast?

Comment: Corey, no, but the e-mail's are all valid, so I'm at a loss as to why else it would.

Comment: @Corey: this is a known issue with some server configurations.

Comment: @Jonathan: See if the VB code example helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. You'll have to use some external code written in class VB or whatever to do it.

Or busy-wait (gak).

Comment: Is it possible to install a hand written COM component on a shared server?

Comment: I guess you'd need administrator approval to do that

Comment: Then you should busy-wait as punishment! Don't let me install software will you? muahahaha

Answer (score 8):

This routine waits any amount of time, and doesn't use CPU:

```
Function asp_Wait(nMilliseconds)
  Dim oShell
  '' VBS: Set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  '' ASP:
  Set oShell= Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Call oShell.run("ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w " & nMilliseconds,1,TRUE) 
  '' Option TRUE: Wait until ping is complete
  '' 1000 milli-second wait is 1 second
End Function
```

Comment: The IP `1.1.1.1` is now taken by CloudFlare, so this will not wait but return in some ms.

Answer (score 5):

there is also a good hta hack that should work.  Look for the A Synthetic Sleep Function here:
http://www.mvps.org/scripting/rube/index.htm

Answer (score 5):

You can use :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sleep</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% 

        function Sleep(seconds)
            set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
            cmd = "%COMSPEC% /c timeout " & seconds & " /nobreak"
            oShell.Run cmd,0,1
        End function

        Sleep(5)

        response.write("End") 
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you using CDO?  Since this is tagged as classic ASP I'm guessing so.

If so if you can use

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=1 '(which is send using pickup)

instead of

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2 '(which is send using port)

It's more reliable because it writes the email to file (usually C:\inetpub\mailroot\pickup) and IIS's SMTP server checks the folder for new mail and will retry if it fails the first time.  The catch is you have to set up SMTP within the IIS snap in.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that this answer is not strictly related to the question, but in trying to answer a question, it just got way to big for comments.

@shahka, the difference is, when you are trying to connect to a DB, the code enters a "wait state", (like a callback), so no CPU time is used. It matters not about what the SESSION or THREAD is doing, it matter what ELSE the CPU/Core is doing.

For an example, find an older non-multi-core CPU. Setup your sample to sleep for 10 seconds, then run for 2-5 seconds or so, then sleep again for 10. Do that about 20,000 times. While it's running, try and use box, see just how responsive it is. Move windows around, watch the CPU usage, etc.

THAT gives you an exmaple of what's happening to this man's Web server.  It becomes unresponsive, because the thread scheduler will tend to 'favor' the CPU/Core that is NOT "spun up" (as we call it).  So, ALL web requests, OS operations, etc will happen on the OTHER core, thus over-loading it, giving it a feeling of being "spun up" as well.

Now, you have times when you can tight-loop a CPU and it will not matter.  But, in all my years of programming, I've never found it necessary to write a tight loop like that (on purpose).  Some of it comes back around to doing things the right way, and the wrong way.  Doing something the wrong way will often WORK, but that does not mean it wworks CORRECTLY.

If you want a good example of this, go and pick just about any virus on the planet, and analyze it.  You'll find that it order to do damage, they (virus writers) often have to do things the "wrong" way.  Sure, it gets the job done, but it also breaks the virus on say, a different language version of Windows, or it crashes the whole machine negating it's purpose, etc.

[Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) was one of my early teachers about this type of stuff, and since I worked with him for many years, and supported, and later QA'ed his software, I learned a lot from him, much in the same waay I'm trying to tell you why your code sample is not good.  strictly speaking, the code is fine.  It works.  It's well written.  But, it does not FUNCTION correctly, and has adverse side effects that other, maaybe amature programmers who might be reading this looking for knowledge do not fully understand.  THAT'S why I did not recommend your sample.

Answer (score 2):

You know, this is one of those times that I think setting up a private MSMQ queue could be a Good Thing.  Put the emails you want to send on the queue, and have a newly developed .NET service do the sending.  That will free up your ASP.NET application, and allow you to manage your sendin' centrally!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a good hack:

http://www.ehow.com/how_2001270_sleep-asp-using-ado.html

The trick is to create an ADO connection object and then try to connect to a non-existant server.  This will block for the duration of the connection object's timeout setting.

Comment: @Bruno: I liked it, too, but I disavow all responsibility for it. :)

Comment: @silverCORE: so is asp classic. Why not save your downvotes for something that actually matters?

Comment: @MusiGenesis I feel the same way than you about ASP, but since there are still some legacy apps that use it, regardless of how developers feel about the technology, i have to care. Plus it makes people lose time to click on a link that does not work. Why not edit your answer instead and use your time for that instead of complaining about down votes?

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that IIS has a default [ASP Script execution time-out](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2275a2ba-5b12-4e18-8266-8a3b0678e419.mspx?mfr=true) default of 90 seconds, so running large scripts that send volumes of email this way will time-out unless you change the asp timeout.

Answer (score 2):

```
var shell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("CHOICE /C:AB /D:A /T:1 > NUL", 1, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server with ASP classic you can use [`WAITFOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql) "query" to stall the script for seconds or even milliseconds:

```sql
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01.234' -- 1,234 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is don't use the server to wait, use the client.
You can write a javascript that keeps calling Send() every second using [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) until the queue is empty.Use an [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to send one email using a server side script. Then on return of the ajax call you can also indicate in the html page that an email has been sent.