# Where to put the sleep function in MSXML request?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, msxml2

I use the following function to check if a RSS url is healthy then consume it:

```
function testUrl(url)
    testUrl=0
    Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    on error resume next
    o.open "GET", url, false
    o.send
    if o.Status = 200 then testUrl = 1
    on error goto 0
    set o=nothing
end function
```

However when the target URL does not respond in a short time I will get timeout error. So I want to use the following function in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6458109/4700922) to terminate the request after 5 seconds if there was no success response but I dont know where to put the asp_Wait(5) and how to cancel the request after 5 seconds? Should I put asp_Wait right after the `o.send` or `o.send` acts synchronous?

```
Function asp_Wait(nMilliseconds)
  Dim oShell
  Set oShell= Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Call oShell.run("ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w " & nMilliseconds,1,TRUE) 
End Function
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760403(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the WinHTTPRequest object you can call the [WaitForResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-waitforresponse) method.

```
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", url, true 'async request
o.send
If o.waitForResponse(5) Then 'wait 5 sec
   ...
Else 'wait timeout exceeded
   ...
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. Just for a reliable use, this answer just solves the issue for healthy but late or long time responses. To handle other errors like error 500 or IP resolve problems, I had to add more error handling options.